# Dispose() affecting a variable it shouldn't?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm having trouble while disposing of a variable, because it seems to affect another variable that it shouldn't. A simplified version of the code is:

```
class Game
{
    Bitmap image;

    public Game(Bitmap image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
}

...
Bitmap tempConvert;
...
tempConvert = new Bitmap(100, 100);
games.Add(new Game(tempConvert));
tempConvert.Dispose();
```

It should be pretty simple: tempconvert gets passed on to Game.image then gets disposed of. Except that tempConvert.Dispose() seems to affect Game.image as well. There's no pointers or adresses or anything, so I don't know why Game.image is affected. Removing tempConvert.Dispose() solves the problem, but creates a massive memory leak.

So then, why is tempConvert.Dispose() affecting Game.image if tempConvert's contents had already been passed on?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: you dont have to dispose bitmap

Comment: The code I showed cycles through a few thousand times, so if I don't dispose of that bitmap the ensuing memory leak crashes the program.

Comment: as @user12864 said Bitmap is passed by reference. its not coppied. it doesnt take extra memory leak. so dont worry. you may dispose it if you really dont need it anymore

Answer (score 4):

`Bitmap` is a reference type.  When you pass it to `new Game`, you're passing a reference to the same instance of `Bitmap`.  Either make another copy of the `Bitmap` or have the `Game` class dispose of it, depending on the desired lifecycle and where else the `Bitmap` is being used.

Comment: Well it's passing just a reference instead of the value, then. That explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a reference of the Bitmap object to your Game class, not the contents of the bitmap. You create 1 Bitmap object, not more; the Bitmap object is used by your initial code and the Game object.

Therefore disposing it in your initial code will affect your Game object.

Comment: Thanks for the help as well.